# Can't launch Spyder after installing with pip

Tags: python, spyder

Python beginner here. I would like to use Spyder as my Python IDE. Alas the standalone version does not include pip and I want to work with "Vanilla Python" rather than Anaconda. So I installed Spyder via
`pip install spyder`, which works fine. However, when running `spyder3` in the command window, nothing happens. I get no error, but Spyder does not launch either. While the Spyder website says custom installation may be tricky, it does not provide a guide on how to get it done. Does someone know how? OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Python Version is 3.10.1 (current)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The command to start Spyder is `spyder`, not `spyder3`. Also, if you're very new to Python, I sincerely recommend you to give our installer another chance because it's way easier to use and more stable. For the packages that don't come with it, please read [our FAQ](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) to learn how to install them in a separate environment.

Comment: Ok thank you. The script folder under spyder-env contains only ```spyder3``` and ```spyder``` is not recognized when run under spyder-env. So to install additional packages, I need Miniconda? That's no problem of course. For the future, it would be nice if you could provide a guide on how to set up Spyder with CPython.

Comment: After all, access to third party software is always at risk of being restricted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Tried again with Python 3.10.4. "spyder" now exists in the Scripts folder and does launch when typing `spyder` in cmd. Works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow this commands:

```
python -m venv spyder-env
spyder-env/Scripts/activate.bat
pip install spyder
```

[more info](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html)

Comment: Tried that already, still same problem... ;(